# combining two different formats of datetime in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, parsing, datetime

I have many csv files that contain date and time information. Problem is that I have two different formats of date.

```
 MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

and

```
MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

I do not want to modify each file. Is there a way to for example modify all the MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS datime to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format in pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) before you merge them into one DataFrame/Series.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas `to_datetime` is pretty versatile, it will understand many different formats.

```
from io import StringIO

d_csv = StringIO("""12/01/2016 01:01:00
12-01-2016 02:02:00""")
d = pd.read_csv(d_csv, header=None)    

d[0] = pd.to_datetime(d[0])

print(d)
```

Output:

```
                    0
0 2016-12-01 01:01:00
1 2016-12-01 02:02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (with a function to parse date format)

```
import pandas as pd

def myparser(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' )

df = pd.read_csv(filename,  parse_dates=True, date_parser=myparser)
```